# C# Process.Start() Not Starting Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to get a C# console application to now execute from a different C# program that is using PS3 Eyes.  There are various Key.X commands to execute certain strings of code, and I'm having trouble with one particular bit--the Process.Start() method.

```
//Take a snapshot from left camera and save to current directory as "snapshot.png"
       case Key.Z:
int left = camLeft.Device.LensCorrection1;
camLeft.Device.LensCorrection1 = 0;
Thread.Sleep(150);
BitmapSource bmpSource = camLeft.Device.BitmapSource as BitmapSource;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmpSource));
encoder.Save(ms);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);                            
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms);
string filepath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(filepath, @"snapshot.png");
bitmap.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Png);
bitmap.Dispose();
camLeft.Device.LensCorrection1 = left;

//Start other C# program that automatically uploads the image to a specified URL
Process.Start("Explicit file path here");
```

The snapshot code works; it takes a picture as it's supposed to, but the `Process.Start` does not seem to execute the other Console Application that I created to upload the image to a URL.  That code is tested and proven to work, but I can post that here too if necessary.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can I assume from your description that nothing happens, not even an exception is thrown? Does the Windows Event Viewer (Application logs) reveal anything about the secondary application?

Comment: Does `Process.Start()` result in an error?  I assume you're actually trying to start a process and not the string you're currently using...

Comment: Are you sure it's not starting, as opposed to starting and immediately ending?  Try putting some logging in it such as "Started at {Time} with arguments {Args}"

Comment: Can you narrow it down to something smaller while still reproducible? e.g. creating and saving a bitmap is unrelated to an inability to run a console app.

Comment: Since you have the source code you would probably be better off putting the routines in a static class and embedding it in your app.

Comment: Is your console programm missing a ReadLine at the end?